# Should I cut back hibiscus/rose mallow for winter in Minnesota?

Tags: flowers, overwintering

I just planted my first Minnesota hardy hibiscus/rose mallow. Should I cut it back in fall or overwinter it intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I live in a similar climate to yours and have a hibiscus.  The directions from the nursery were to cut it back to the ground and cover with several inches of mulch in the fall.  I have followed these instructions and had no problems.

The hardy hibiscus varieties start slow in the spring so I can plant crocus or scilla in the same area and they are over and down with before the hibiscus shows up.

If you decide not to cut it back the stems will die back to the ground anyway.  It will act to collect snow and act as a perch for winter birds.